# Why this value is '29801000199002684333' long in generation of xsd why not varchar

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I was checking xml to xsd format. But when I tried to convert xml format data into xsd with following code which I get from this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xsd/xsd_validation.htm
I wonder why 20 digits of number shows long type and it gives me following error

> SAX Exception: cvc-maxInclusive-valid: Value '29801000199002684333' is
>   not facet-valid with respect to maxInclusive '9223372036854775807' for
>   type 'long'.

with following codes

```
  SchemaFactory factory =
           SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
   Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new File("out.xsd"));
   Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
   validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File("in.xml")));
```

How I could avoid from this problem I wanted to see this data in varchar type not in long type

XSD format

```
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="account" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:long"/>
<xsd:element name="branchBIC" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="branchCode" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:int"/>
<xsd:element name="currencyIsoCode" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
   </xsd:sequence>
```

XML format

```
   <account>40700810256895634168</account>
      <branchBIC>040037470</branchBIC>
       <branchCode>1</branchCode>
     <currencyIsoCode>RUR</currencyIsoCode>
```

Comment: Account numbers and bank BIC numbers are not really numbers, just like telephone numbers are not numbers. (They are not numbers because you'll never do arithmetic on them - they are really identifiers, or labels instead). You should not model them in your XSD with the data types `long` or `int`. Use a string type instead, and possibly add restrictions such as a regex to make it so that it can contain only digits.

Comment: Likely a **bug**, your varchar ('`xsd:string`) seems the sole right solution.

Comment: Sir Jesper you don't understand me well I think. I'm not doing it . I get only String and writing it into file and from file I'm generating written xml into xsd with help of following class   XsdGen gen = new XsdGen();
        gen.parse(new File("in.xml"));
        File out = new File("out.xsd");
        gen.write(new FileOutputStream(out)); Then it automatically writes long type

Comment: I couldn't it manipulate manually everything should be automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire post is about XML, XSD, and Java, yet your problem lies with none of those.  Your posted XSD says that `account` is of type `xsd:long`, yet your XML has `account` value that exceeds the maximum allowed value for `xsd:long`.  Therefore, your XML is invalid per your XSD as it should be.

From your comments, it appears that you're unhappy that the tool you're using has chosen a type `xsd:long` rather than `xsd:string`.  This should have been a prominent part of your question, not buried in the comments, as the `XsdGen` class you're using lies at the basis of your problem.

Since your question pertains specifically to [xsd-gen](https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen), you should raise an [issue](https://github.com/wiztools/xsd-gen/issues) with the developers of that tool.

Comment: Sorry sir I'm new in this community. Thank you for you wise advice

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a schema from an XML instance, you're asking the tool to do a lot of guesswork. For example you're asking it to guess whether 3872-12-14 is intended to be a date or whether it is just some random string. The more examples it has to go on, the more likely it is to guess correctly, but it is always going to be wrong some of the time. When it sees an account number, how is it to know whether it is an integer or a string? The difference is important, because if it chooses xs:integer then leading zeros will be considered insignificant and will be lost. All tools for schema generation therefore require a human being to review the output and fine-tune it. Some tools may make better guesses than others, but none of them will ever be perfect, because the process requires semantic understanding of the data.